# Datatable Row grouping collapse and Expand - Not able to understand Variable

Tags: laravel, datatable

Good Morning,
I am new to coding and learning from stack overflow and youtube. I am trying to use Datatable Row grouping collapse and Expand. Every thing work perfectly for grouping but stuck at doing collapse and Expand when click on group row. I found few solation but stuck at some point in code where i did not understand where the variable is taken. Code is as below

```
 $('#getsocietywidecustomerdetails tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function () {
  var currentOrder = dt_customer.order()[0];
  //alert(currentOrder);
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  alert(name);
  collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
  dt_customer.draw(false);
});
```

here i am not able to understand "name" ( $(this).data('name') ).

Hope my question is clear and appreciated for help to understand the same